# Button mouse over ForeColour change

Tags: c#, mouseover

To create a mouse over button I use this code

```
    private void btnCreateAccount_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnCreateAccount.ForeColor = Color.Gold;
    }

    private void btnCreateAccount_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnCreateAccount.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

The mouse over button works however when I hover over the button there is a good at least 1 second delay. I would think that it should change colour as soon as the mouse is placed over the button and not with a (in my opinion) too long delay.

Is there any way of fixing that code by like refreshing the button or something along those lines? or perhaps someone has a code that works perfectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handling the [Mouse **Hover**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx) event. This will require the cursor to be still for a short while in order to fire.

> The pause required for this event to be raised is specified in milliseconds by the [MouseHoverTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousehovertime(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

This is read only.

Normally if you want the colour to change immediately you should handle the [Mouse **Enter**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
private void btnCreateAccount_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnCreateAccount.ForeColor = Color.Gold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for!!